# AChartEngine doesn't seem to be responding to my commands

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm trying to use AChartEngine to build a really, really simplified chart for an app I'm creating.  Using data stored in a global class, I'm trying to create a horizontal bar chart that shows a single variable on each line, with invisible axes, and with the value of each variable at the end of each respective bar.  It should look almost as if each variable was held in a separate `TableRow` of a `TableLayout` and each bar was in the next column of the respective row, with the value of that variable next to the bar (or in a third column).

I know how to do some of this stuff, theoretically, and have yet to figure out other parts.  I have the following simple setup that I derived from a tutorial and some of the sample code provided:

```
private GraphicalView mChart;

private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

private XYSeries mCurrentSeries;

private XYSeriesRenderer mCurrentRenderer;

private void initChart() {
    mCurrentSeries = new XYSeries("Sample Data");
    mDataset.addSeries(mCurrentSeries);
    mCurrentRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(mCurrentRenderer);
    mRenderer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(1, "xyzxyzxyz");
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(2, "abcabca");
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(3, "tqrstuvwx");
    mRenderer.setBarSpacing(1);
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{0,0,0,0});
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
    mRenderer.setShowLabels(true);
    mRenderer.setShowAxes(false);
    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
    mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}

private void addSampleData() {
    mCurrentSeries.add(1, 85);
    mCurrentSeries.add(2, 75);
    mCurrentSeries.add(3, 70);
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    if (mChart == null) {
        initChart();
        addSampleData();
        mChart = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);
        layout.addView(mChart);
    } else {
        mChart.repaint();
    }
}
```

I've got the following questions about the code:

1. I've gathered that the renderers are what do the work of, you know, rendering the charts.  But what is the difference between, in my case, `mRenderer` and `mCurrentRenderer`?
2. Right now, `setShowAxes()` is `false`, but the axes are still showing.  Why is that?
3. `setShowLabels()` is `true`, which seems right because I need the variables to show, but the x-axis of the chart is positioned such that it squishes any of the variable labels.  How do I make the x-axis give enough space to display longest variable, or wrap the text of the label after a certain number of characters?
4. I don't want this chart to look like a typical chart, I want it to display as I described above.  One part of achieving this is setting the background color to transparent.  I did so, but it still shows up as black even though the background color of the parent layout is `D0E4F7`.  I also used `setGridColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)` and that seems to work, allowing the grid color to become my layout background color.  However, I still need the background of the areas outside of the grid to be transparent.
5. I am using `setBarSpacing()` and that seems to be working fine, but I also need to set the width of each bar.  What method can I use to do that?
6. I need the chart to not fill the entire view, but rather fit into a specific part of the view.  The `LinearLayout` of the chart will be wrapped in a `RelativeLayout` and a `ScrollView` in order to properly position it on the screen.  In the XML, I've set `layout_weight="0"` and specified `layout_height="200dp"`.  This works, but causes all of the text to be "squished" vertically.  How do I resize while avoiding this?
7. Is AChartEngine even the right library to be using for this, or am I trying to fit a square peg into a round hole?

Thank you for any and all help.  I am happy to post more code snippets as needed.

EDIT: Follow-up to Dan's responses:

(1) Thanks for that explanation, that definitely helps.  I'm assuming they can both be called in the `initChart()` method?

(2) Both the X and Y axes are showing.

(3) Is there a way to move the axis?  The article you linked isn't the same issue as mine.  My labels are outside of the grid, not on the bars, but on the ticks.

(4) I realize I never really asked a question here - how do I set the area around the grid to be transparent?

(5)  I'm not sure what you mean by this?  What method can I use to manually set the width of each bar?

(6) I'm not sure why you're skipping this - are you implying it relates to (3)?

(7) Here's where I really think you're misinterpreting where I'm coming from.  I'm not doubting the validity or quality of AChartEngine - I opted to begin working with it because so many people pointed to it as a quality option.  When I said "doesn't seem to be responding to my commands", I didn't mean to imply that it was unresponsive, I thought it was clear that I simply was unable to get it to do what I wanted it to do.

What I am wondering when I ask (7) is if AChartEngine is truly the right option, or if I am expecting it to do things that it isn't built to do?  When I am building a bar chart and then opting to remove all of the features (axes, labels, background, dynamic scales, etc) and literally display just the bar itself on a set scale (and therefore using AChartEngine for it's ability to create a bar at a specified length given an input variable), I wonder if I am doing the charting equivalent of using an airplane to get to the grocery store.

I was hoping, in part, that this post would elicit either "yes, it's the right option, that makes sense", or "no, you're trying to go hunting with hand grenades, you can do what you want in a much simpler way".  I think it's a legit question, and one that shouldn't offend you in the least bit.  Just because it's worked for 5000+ apps in the past does not mean it's the right solution for what I'm trying to do.  Any constructive thoughts you might have on whether it is in fact the right choice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. `mCurrentRenderer` defines the way the current series is to be displayed while `mRenderer` defines the way the entire chart is to be displayed in general.
2. What axes are still showing? If what you say is true then this may be called a potential bug. I also have no idea what version of AChartEngine you are trying to use. Can you please post a screenshot?
3. Horizontal bar chart known [issue](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=203). To move the axis: `renderer.setMargins([top, left, bottom, right]);`
4. Try `renderer.setMarginsColor(color)`.
5. `setBarWidth()` can be used for series with only one item (one single bar in a series). For the other series, you can just play with the `setBarSpacing()` parameter which changes the bar width as a side effect.
6. Use `renderer.setInScroll(true);`
7. AChartEngine is definitely a good choice for displaying a lot of chart types. However, the horizontal bar chart (the bars are horizontally displayed) is in an experimental mode and I usually don't advise anyone using that unless they really want to. There are definitely a few other charting engines, but I haven't ever evaluated one, so I cannot say it there is a better one or how good the others are. Maybe time will tell.

Once you figure this out, if you will go on the AChartEngine route, I suggest you post shorter questions ideally with just one issue you have. Otherwise, these are hard to answer all together or may take forever to figure out.

Comment: Dan, thanks for the response.  I've followed up on each of your responses in my EDIT in the original post.  I look forward to your replies.

Comment: @user2163853 I updated most of my answer. Please check again.

Comment: Hey thanks Dan.  These answers are definitely helpful.  I plan to try to implement tonight and see where it takes me.  I appreciate your help.